# Why do I get asn1 error for ca-bundle.trust.crt on CentOS?

Tags: ruby, openssl, centos, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to add all the pem and crt files in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` to an `OpenSSL::X509::Store` with this code:

```
require 'openssl'

store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
Dir.glob('/etc/pki/tls/certs/*.{pem,crt}') do |cert_path|
  puts cert_path
  cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(IO.read(cert_path))
  store.add_cert(cert)
end
```

And when it gets to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt` the `OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new` raises this error:

```
cert_test.rb:6:in `initialize': nested asn1 error (OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError)
    from cert_test.rb:6:in `new'
    from cert_test.rb:6:in `block in <main>'
    from cert_test.rb:4:in `glob'
    from cert_test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Anyone know what that `ca-bundle.trust.crt` is or why ruby's openssl can't read it?

For what it's worth, I don't get any errors when I run:

```
openssl x509 -text -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the whole reason I'm even trying to read all the certs in that directory is because I want to tell chef to get its trusted certs there and this is (more or less) how chef reads the certs: https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/72575c3c46c89b9c74d63baceaaf2237ed9e0e6f/lib/chef/http/ssl_policies.rb#L80-84

Comment: *`ca-bundle.trust.crt`* - instead of using the CA Zoo with the hundreds of CAs and Subordinate CAs, why not tell Chef to use the one true CA that actually certifies the site. This way the other unrelated CAs can't claim to certify the site.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bundle of "Trusted Certificates".

The x509 man page talks about them some.

> TRUST SETTINGS
>
> Please note these options are currently experimental and may well change.
>
> A trusted certificate is an ordinary certificate which has several additional pieces of information attached to it such as the permitted and prohibited uses of the certificate and an "alias".
>
> Normally when a certificate is being verified at least one certificate must be "trusted". By default a trusted certificate must be stored locally and must be a root CA: any certificate chain ending in this CA is then usable for any purpose.
>
> Trust settings currently are only used with a root CA. They allow a finer control over the purposes the root CA can be used for. For example a CA may be trusted for SSL client but not SSL server use.
>
> See the description of the verify utility for more information on the meaning of trust settings.
>
> Future versions of OpenSSL will recognize trust settings on any certificate: not just root CAs.

and

> The PEM format uses the header and footer lines:
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> it will also handle files containing:
>
> -----BEGIN X509 CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----END X509 CERTIFICATE-----
>
> Trusted certificates have the lines
>
> -----BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----END TRUSTED CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: I did see those different headers and footers in the file, but that doesn't really explain why Ruby's openssl cannot read them. They're still in PEM form right? This page says it should be able to read pem files: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html

Comment: `PEM` is an encoding not a "type". Presumably it can't handle trusted certs and only regular certs but I have no idea.

Comment: Quick look makes it seem like it should support that file but might dump trust information but I have no real confidence that I looked at the right places and have understood things correctly. But as a general rule openssl has different functions for different things and historically many projects have used subtly wrong functions for a very long time before noticing.